# Naming object and its string representation

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, naming

Sirs, I have a lot of places in my code where method receives raw user input as `string`, then `TryParse`s it to actual data type (`decimal`, `enum`, etc). The object I name by its actual purpose (for example, `decimal amount`). But I can't figure what is the best naming convention for raw `string`s? `rawAmount`? `amountString`? `amount_raw`? something else? Please let me know what do you think.

Comment: how about inputAmount and actualAmount

Answer (score 1):

I always go:

```
string amountStr = GetInput();
double amount = double.Parse(amountStr);
```